# Bash for loop printing the statement

Tags: bash

I was trying to print out some numbers from 1 to 20 with an increment of 2

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..20..2} 
do
    echo $i
done
```

and this is what it has printed out

{0..20..2}

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What version of bash are you using? Setting the step value is only after v4.0...

Comment: thank you very much. This was the reason.

Comment: You may consider using a C-style `for` loop: `for ((i=0; i<=20; i+=2)); do echo $i; done`

Comment: Or `seq 0 2 20`

Comment: @Jon, ...suboptimal. `seq` isn't part of bash and isn't specified by POSIX, so you pay external-executable startup costs, and whether it works (and _how_ it works) is entirely at the grace of your operating system vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in for loops syntax:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=0; c<=20; c+=2 ))
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Yes, using the built-in for loop probably is a better idea.